# python regex for current time

Tags: python, regex, time

I am having some trouble with regex it seems in creating a regex that matches time in the format "hh/mm/ss". I am making an alarm clock in python.

here's what I currently have:

```
import time, re

time_pattern = re.compile(r'([0-2][0-4])/([0-5][0-9])/([0-5][0-9])')

alarm_set = input("Set alarm time (hh/mm/ss): ")

while not time_pattern.match(alarm_set):

    print('Invalid input. Must be expressed in "hh/mm/ss"')
    alarm_set = input("Set alarm time (hh/mm/ss): ")
```

But for some reason when I try to match '18/00/00', it doesn't match. I have no idea why this isn't working. Especially because it matches '24/59/59' and '00/00/00' perfectly fine. It is weird because to me, my regex seems fine.

Any help would be much appreciated =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't match `18/00/00` because you match the hour using:

```
[0-2][0-4]
```

You could fix it by using

```
[0-1][0-9]|2[0-4]
```

instead.

A better approach might be to use [`strptime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) instead of using a regex.

Comment: Oh how silly of me. Thank you so much. I shall investigate this strptime function you speak of.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the [0-4] portion is what makes **18**/00/00 not match?